# Write and Save As with python in plugin QGIS

Tags: python, qgis

I try to make plugin in QGIS and i want to make save as button but i got error message like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\latih\latihdialog.py", line 69, in 

saveAs
    if not filename.isEmpty():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'
```

I write my code like this :

```
cariButton = self.ui.btnCari
QtCore.QObject.connect(cariButton,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.cari)
saveButton = self.ui.btnSave     
QtCore.QObject.connect(saveButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.saveAs)   

def  cari(self, event=None):
    #open dialog
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')         

self.ui.lineFile.setText(filename)
    #panggil isi data

self.isiDataFile(filename)

def isiDataFile(self, nmfile):
        #buka dengan open mode baca
        teksFile = open(nmfile, 'r').read()

self.ui.textFile.setText(teksFile)

def _save(self, filename):        
    f = open( filename, "w" )
        f.write( "%s" % self.lineFile.text() )
f.close()
def savefile(self):
     if self.filename:
          self._save( "%s" % self.filename )
else:
          self.saveAs()

def saveAs(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog(self).getSaveFileName()
        if not filename.isEmpty():
            _filename = "%s" % filename
            self._save( _filename )
            self.setFilename( _filename )
```

I try to save file in different format

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is:

```
   filename = QtGui.QFileDialog(self).getSaveFileName()
    if not filename.isEmpty():
```

`filename` is a `unicode` object, which doesn't have an `isEmpty()` method. Try:

```
 if filename != "":
```

or, as [empty strings are `False`-y](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
if filename:
```

Comment: The problem is the python API change from QGIS 1.8 to 2.0. Strings are no longer represented as `QString` objects, but instead are proper python `unicode` objects. An alternative approach would be `if not filename:`

Comment: sorry i was late to reply, but when i change the code i got another error, its say:
[>File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\latih\latihdialog.py", line 71, in saveAs
    self._save( _filename )
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\latih\latihdialog.py", line 59, in _save
    f.write( "%s" % self.nmfile.text() )
AttributeError: 'latihDialog' object has no attribute 'nmfile'<] 

Its because i use the older python code? i use python 3

Comment: No, I think that is because `'latihDialog' object has no attribute 'nmfile'`. *Read your error messages*. I don't know what attributes a `latihDialog` does have; is this your own custom class?

Comment: No its the dialog in the QGIS plugin, my plugin have name "latih"

Comment: Then I suggest you open another question, including the code relating to `latihDialog`